# SQL: Get first occurence of rows based on comparison criteria

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to think of a precise way of getting down to this problem of SQL.

I have a table containing 3 columns:

```
| A      | B | C |
|--------|---|---|
| foo    | 1 | 0 |
| foo    | 1 | 1 |
| bar    | 2 | 0 |
| bar    | 2 | 1 |
| foobar | 3 | 0 |
| foobar | 3 | 1 |
| foobar | 3 | 2 |
| foobar | 3 | 4 |
```

I would like to capture table where for each partition column `A`, the last  occurrence of column `B` such `B` is greater than or equal largest value of column `C`

That is:

```
| A      | B | C |
|--------|---|---|
| foo    | 1 | 1 |
| bar    | 2 | 1 |
| foobar | 3 | 2 |
```

*Assumption*: `A` is partition key over which `B` and `C` are sorted ascending order.

Comment: Your output data seems to have the *last* occurrence of column B that is >= C

Comment: What defines the `first` occurrence of column B? Is there an `id` type column that the data can be sorted by?

Comment: Define 'first'.

Comment: @jOasis . . . What does "last" occurrence mean?  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets and your rows don't seem to have an ordering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use grouping with inequality `B >= C`:

```
select A, B, max(C) as C
  from tab 
 where B >= C
 group by A, B
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=42188928e62ec63a84ea802c2d51d0a2)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

This is how I interpret your requirement:

```
select A, B as D, max(case when B >= C then C end) as E
from tablename
group by A, B
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fDbqYyHmAR4hC91o2PP7L5/1).

Answer (score 0):

For this, I have used `Group by` to arrange identical `A` columns into groups and `MAX()` function returns the largest value of the `C` column with condition `B >= C` which picks only column where column `B` is greater than or equal to column `C`

```
SELECT A,B,MAX(C) AS C from tablename
WHERE B >= C
GROUP BY B,A
```

Hope this could solve your problem.